# Validation Loss is increase and validation accuracy is decrese on every epochs in my RNN Model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on abusive and violent content detection. When I train my model, the training log is as follows:

```
Train on 9087 samples, validate on 2125 samples
Epoch 1/5
9087/9087 [==============================] - 33s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3193 - accuracy: 0.8603 -         val_loss: 0.2314 - val_accuracy: 0.9322
Epoch 2/5
9087/9087 [==============================] - 33s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1787 - accuracy: 0.9440 - val_loss: 0.2039 - val_accuracy: 0.9356
Epoch 3/5
9087/9087 [==============================] - 32s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1148 - accuracy: 0.9637 - val_loss: 0.2569 - val_accuracy: 0.9180
Epoch 4/5
9087/9087 [==============================] - 33s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0805 - accuracy: 0.9738 - val_loss: 0.3409 - val_accuracy: 0.9047
Epoch 5/5
9087/9087 [==============================] - 36s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0599 - accuracy: 0.9795 - val_loss: 0.3661 - val_accuracy: 0.9082
```

[You can see in this graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDuMU.png)

As you can see, the train loss and accuracy decreases but the validation loss and accuracy increases..

The code for the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(8941, 256,input_length=20))
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history=model.fit(x, x_test,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=5,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(y, y_test))
```

Help would be appriciated.

Comment: Your final layer has 4 nodes, but you're using a binary loss function. If 4 is correct, then you'll want to use a softmax activation instead of sigmoid, and the loss should be a categorical_cross_entropy instead of binary.

Comment: When i use categorical_cross_entropy loss reaches at 32.04 and i reduce learning rate and increase batch size and dropout but it does not work.

Comment: What is the format of your labels please? For CCe they will need to be one-hot encoded. You can do this with sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder

Comment: Actually using sparse_categorical_cross_entropy is easier for label encoding, as you don't have to one-hot them. You only need to convert them to integers.
For example, if you have a pandas dataframe:
`label_encoder = LabelEncoder() \
df['labels'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['labels'])`

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41921/sparse-categorical-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-keras-accuracy might help

Comment: Here the link [link](https://github.com/ujas3279/Abusive-And-Vioilent-Content-Detection) of my github repositories please fork this and help me to solve this problem.i am very thankful to you.

Comment: Ah ok, looking at your training data, this is a multi-label classification problem (not multi-class), as one line of text can have multiple classifications. Apologies I don't have experience with this :/

Comment: ok no problem and thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on your data, but it seems like the model overfits the train set very quickly (after the second epoch).

Try:

1. Reduce your learning rate
2. Increase your batch size
3. Add regularization
4. Increase your dropout rate

Furthermore, it seems like you use `binary_crossentropy` while your model outputs a 4-length output for each sample: `model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))` this might cause problems too.

Comment: i tried all the step you mentioned but it still dose not solve this problem.here the [link](https://github.com/ujas3279/Abusive-And-Vioilent-Content-Detection) of my github repositories please help me to solve this problem. i am very thankful to you.